# Is getElementById() method not available for tables

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check if there exists an element with a particular id inside a table, below is my code.

HTML:

```
<table id="age-table">
        <tr>
            <td id="age-header">Your age:</td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="age" value="young"/> under 18
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="age" value="mature"/> 18 to 50
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="age" value="senior"/> after 60
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And script:

```
    <script>
        var table = document.getElementById('age-table');
        var lables = table.getElementsByTagName('label');
        console.log(lables);
        var findid = table.getElementById('age-header'); //throws error table.getElementById() is not a function.

    </script>
```

I can achieve what I want by using contains() like this

```
var id = document.getElementById('age-header');
var findid = table.contains(id);
console.log(findid);
```

But I didn't understand why `table.getElementsByTagName('label')` worked, but `table.getElementById('age-header')` threw error. Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `getElementById` is only available for the `Document` object. If you think about it, it makes sense, because IDs are supposed to be unique across a document, not a DOM element.

Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Answer (score 0):

The `document` is the instance of HTMLDocument.

[image]

But the element (in your example, `table`) is the instance of HTMLDivElement.

[image]

You can easily check these prototype's different.